# Attaching JS variable to form on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a variable set by the user after the page has completed loading.

This is stored in the following:

```
var finalX;
```

I have a form that will be submitted once this value has been set.

I need to attach it to the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="x" />
```

As it can change at any time up until the form is submitted, it needs to select it as the form button is clicked.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: are you using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.submit()` function to capture the actual submission of the form.

> [Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Then you can inject the hidden field with it's appropriate value:

```
$( "#your_form" ).submit( function() {

  console.log( "Handler for .submit() called." );

  $( "input", {
    "type": "hidden",
    "name": "x",
    "value": your_hidden_value
  } ).appendTo( "#your_form" );

});
```

If the hidden field is already in your HTML, you can just set the value:

```
$( "#your_form" ).submit( function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  $( "input:hidden[name='x']" ).val( your_hidden_value )
});
```

Comment: I'm getting as far as the console logging the message but the value isn't being attached to the input! My input ID is the same as where you've put hidden_input and I've attached finalX where you put your_hidden_value! Any ideas?

Comment: @sark9012 - which of the two solutions I provided are you using?

Comment: The second of the two!

Comment: @sark9012 - ok. Does your hidden input have the appropriate `id` attribute? In my code, I used `"#hidden_input"` just as an example. You can change that to the real `id` attribute that is in your HTML.

Comment: In both, it's xcoordinate. I've checked and they match. In the jQuery do I need to do anything to be more specific to that input id?

Comment: @sark9012 - I've updated my code to reflect the input element you provided in your question. I'm now selecting the hidden input element according to it's `name` attribute which you have set to "x".

Comment: I've fixed it bud, your original way would have worked. finalX was going out of scope as I had it within a click! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @sark9012 - no problem! Glad to help; Happy coding! I'm leaving my answer as it is because it more accurately reflects the content of your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple submit listener:

```
<form onsubmit="this.x.value = finalX;" ...>
```

Or attach it onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.forms['formName'].onsubmit = function() {
    this.x.value = finalX;
  }
}
```

or if you have multiple submit listeners:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.forms['formID'].addEventListener('submit',function(){this.x.value=finalX},false)
}
```

Comment: Does it matter if finalX is set above or below the form?

Comment: It should be above, but as long as it's created before the form is submitted then it will work. If the script fails completely, the form will submit with the default value for *form.x*.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery aproach:

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function(e) {
    this.x.value = finalX;
});
```

Comment: Why cancel submit, then call it? Just set the value and let the event run its course. The entire body of the function can be `this.x.value = finalX`.

Comment: Js & jQuery mixing .. Why don't you just use javascript ? With addeventlistener ?

Comment: I have not seen the op say he used jQuery

Comment: I am using jQuery so it's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answers you may also consider this

Where ever `finalX` value is set, you may just add the following line below it

```
$('#yourForm input[name=X]').val(finalX);
```

If you are not using jQuery and assuming that you have only one `input[name="X"]`element you may try the following line instead

```
var ele = document.getElementsByName("X");
if(ele.length > 0) ele[0].value =  finalX;
```